# my appendix title did not goes to top of the page and also my table and fig did not fix to side by side

Tags: tables, floats, appendix

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices-C}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\LARGE Appendices-C}
\end{center}
\section{algorithm}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}%
        \large
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    Y     & X   \\
    \midrule

    0.003049 & -165 \\
    17.34357 & -156 \\
    33.01277 & -147 \\
    47.01361 & -138 \\
    59.34909 & -129 \\
    70.02217 & -120 \\
    79.03583 & -111 \\
    86.39305 & -102 \\
    92.09681 & -93 \\
    96.15008 & -84 \\
    98.55585 & -75 \\
    99.31709 & -66 \\
    98.43678 & -57 \\
    95.91789 & -48 \\
    91.7634 & -39 \\
    85.97629 & -30 \\
    78.55954 & -21 \\
    69.51613 & -12 \\
    58.84903 & -3 \\
    46.56122 & 6 \\
    32.65568 & 15 \\
    17.13538 & 24 \\
    0.003302 & 33 \\

\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \label{A}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{p1}
        \captionof{figure}{P1}
        \label{ }
    \end{minipage}
        \caption{P1 profile coordinates}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The only reason to use a `table` environment is to allow it to float (move away from where it was mentioned in the code). If you absolutely don't want this behaviour, don't use `table`. In  this specific case, using the optional argument of the `table` environment (as in `\begin{table}[hbp]`) might already be sufficient.

Comment: The two minipages are not positioned side by side since the combined widths add up to more than 1 \textwidth. Reduce the width of the first minipage.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy @leandriis your suggestion worked very well. I spend so much time sorting this problem but with your simple guide I am able to resolve it.